# How to show the password after creating an instance using EC2 CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm running the below command to create an instace from an existing AMI :

```
'ec2-run-instances ami-e1***** --name "INSTANCE_NAME" -t t1.micro --aws-access-key %AWS_ACCESS_KEY% --aws-secret-key %AWS_SECRET_KEY%'
```

How can I display the instance password after I create this instance by EC2 Cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming windows instance:

```
aws ec2 get-password-data --instance-id <your-windows-instance-id>
```

[GetPasswordData](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/get-password-data.html)

> Retrieves the encrypted administrator password for an instance running
>   Windows

Comment: I used this command: `ec2-get-password i-******** -k KEY_VALUE --aws-access-key ACCESS_KEY --aws-secret-key SECERT_KEY` [link] for CLI Reference (API Version 2015-10-01) –